# I'm looking for the name of the specific properties of physical quantities - if it already exists

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, conventions

My working names are *extensivity* or *degree of nonaditivity* of this quantity, but I wonder if there exist a generic term of its.

*Degree of nonaditivity*  of quantity $f$ is defined as a minimal $k$, such that $f$ of system is equal to the sum of $f$ of its subsystems with $\leq k$ elements, i.e.

$$ f(\{x_{1}...x_{n}\})=\sum_{S\subseteq\{x_{1}...x_{n}\},|S|\leq k}f(S) $$

For instance, the (nonrelativistic) mass: If we have a system with masses of elements $ (m_{1}...m_{n}) $, then the total mass is simply a sum $ \sum_{1}^{n}m_{i} $.  So, *degree of nonaditivity* of mass is $1$

In contrast, this does not work for energy. But energy of the full system is still the sum of energies of parts plus energy of interactions between *pairs* of elements of system, $$E_{total}=\sum_{i}E_{i}+\sum_{\{i,j\}}E_{ij}$$
 So, *degree of nonaditivity* of energy is $2$ and so on.

Comment: I do not believe that quantity has a name. I would also add that I don't think it is true, in general, that energy has a degree of non-additivity of 2 (or at the very least it will depend on what you are considering as an "element" of your system). Extensivity would not be a good name as it would be too easily confused with he concept of [extensivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) in thermodynamics and statistical mechanics, (and statistical mechanics is one of the areas most likely to care about this type of concept).

Comment: Yes, energy does not work so simple in general. The goals of my formula are simplicity and clarity.